# Solve for $x$ in $ \sin x + \sin x \cos x - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2})= 0 $

Tags: trigonometry

How can to solve for $x$ in $$ \sin x + \sin x \cos x - \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2} \right)= 0.$$

My try:
$$ \sin x + \sin x \cos x = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2} \right) $$
$$  (\sin x + \sin x \cos x)^2 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^2
$$
$$ \sin^2x + 2\sin^2 x \cos x + \sin^2x \cos^2x - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^2 =  0
$$

$$ \sin^2 x( 1 + 2 \cos x + \cos^2 x ) - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^2 = 0
$$

$$ (1 - \cos^2x)( 1 + 2 \cos x + \cos^2 x ) - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^2 = 0
$$

$$ 1 + 2 \cos x + \cos^2 x - \cos^2 x - 2 \cos^3 x - \cos^4 x- (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^2 = 0
$$

$$ 1 + 2 \cos x - 2 \cos^3 x - \cos^4x -(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^2 = 0
$$

thx for all ur help

Comment: Unless you add more details and show your attempts to solve, this will be a closed question soon. I will show you a nice symmetry in the equation, which points out some solutions even befor we solve it completely. $$\sin x \left(1+\cos x\right)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right).$$ As a general strategy you can replace both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ by $\tan (x/2)$ using double angle formulas.

Comment: No matter which way you try to solve this (tangent half angle substitution, or by immediate squaring as you did), it seems you'll end up with a quartic equation. There are ways to solve those analytically, but they're very difficult.

Comment: Either you use the tangent half angle identities as suggest by Bumblebee or use the substitution $cosx=t$ and you end up with a quartic equation. I beg to ask, where did this question come from and are there any hints/tools as to how a student is supposed to solve this?

Comment: the question is somewhere from physics, which is related to the topic of projectile motion

Comment: from your last equation, $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$. finally check your solutions in the original equation

Answer (score 1):

Using the tangent half-angle substitution, you end with
$$\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) t^4+2 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) t^2-8 t+(1+\sqrt{2})=0$$By inspection (with all these $1$'s and $\sqrt{2}$'s),  $\color{red}{t=(\sqrt{2}-1)}$ is a root.

Factoring, we are left with
$$\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) t^3+t^2+\left(1+3 \sqrt{2}\right) t-(3+2 \sqrt{2})=0$$ for which $$\Delta=-64 \left(63+44 \sqrt{2}\right) \quad <0$$ Using the hyperbolic method for only one real root which is (!!)
$$\color{red}{t=\frac{1}{3} \left(1-\sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{3-\sqrt{2}} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3}
   \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{14} \sqrt{\frac{1}{7} \left(173+81
   \sqrt{2}\right)}\right)\right)\right)}$$ I shall not try to find what is this number which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

To the first root corresponds
$$x_1=2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)=\frac \pi 4+2k\pi$$
and the second is
$$x_2\sim 2\tan ^{-1}(0.778669) \sim 1.323197$$

Answer (score 0):

You may continue with

$$ 1 + 2 \cos x - 2 \cos^3 x - \cos^4x -(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{2})^2 = 0
$$

knowing that $ \cos x = \frac1{\sqrt2} $ is a solution from inspection, as commented. So, factorize  the equation as

$$ (\cos x - \frac1{\sqrt2})(\cos^3x +(2+\frac1{\sqrt2})\cos^2x+ (\frac12+\sqrt2)\cos x-1+\frac1{2\sqrt2})=0
$$
where the cubic polynomial has one real root that can be calculated analytically with the Cardano formula.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, $\pi/4$, is immediately extracted from the form of the given equation, as [Bumblebee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/156886/bumblebee) commented after a few seconds as the question was posted:
$$
\sin x (1+\cos x)=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt2} \right)\ .
$$
There are two solutions in $[0,2\pi]$, as the following pari/gp-raw plot shows it:

``````````````````````````````````````````````````
? plot(x=0, 2*Pi, sin(x) + sin(x)*cos(x) - (1/sqrt(2) + 1/2) )

 0.088734 |'''''''_x""x_'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''|
          ```````x``````x`````````````````````````````````````````````````
          |     x        "_                                              |
          |    x           _                                             |
          |   _             x                                            |
          |                  x                                           |
          |  "                x                                          |
          | _                  x                                         |
          |                     "_                                       |
          |x                      x_                                     |
          _                         xx____                               _
          |                               """"xx                         |
          |                                     "x                      x|
          |                                       "_                     |
          |                                         x                  " |
          |                                          x                _  |
          |                                           x                  |
          |                                            x             "   |
          |                                             "           x    |
          |                                              "_        x     |
          |                                                x      x      |
-2.502948 |................................................."x__x".......|
          0                                                       6.283185
?
``````````````````````````````````````````````````

Both solutions appear in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$.

To see that the second solution is not a "beautiful solution", i.e. a(n easy) rational multiple of $\pi$, we have to solve explicitly.

Numerically, this is simple. In sage, we have for instance:

```
? \p 80
   realprecision = 96 significant digits (80 digits displayed)
? c1 = solve(c=0, 0.5, 1 + 2*c - 2*c^3 - c^4 - (1/sqrt(2) + 1/2)^2)
%13 = 0.24507719212504432088553369017245407857420915894751612868529986637012882459682178
? c2 = solve(c=0.5, 1, 1 + 2*c - 2*c^3 - c^4 - (1/sqrt(2) + 1/2)^2)
%14 = 0.70710678118654752440084436210484903928483593768847403658833986899536623923105352
? acos(c1)/Pi
%15 = 0.42118669118081648201964584654917700002378936841121635895529014330812148926140359
? acos(c2)/Pi
%16 = 0.25000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Here, we have used the equation of degree four from the OP in the unknown $c$, extracted to correspond to $\cos x$. The solution $c_2=1/\sqrt2$ corresponds to $x=\arccos c_2=\pi/4$. But $c_1$ "looks ugly".

To get it explicitly, we can factorize in [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), using the letter $a$ for $\sqrt 2$ and $C$ as unknown (playing the rolw of $\cos x$):

```
sage: K.<a> = QuadraticField(2)
sage: R.<C> = PolynomialRing(K)
sage: factor(1 + 2*C - 2*C^3 - C^4 - (1/a + 1/2)^2)
(-1) * (C - 1/2*a) * (C^3 + (1/2*a + 2)*C^2 + (a + 1/2)*C + 1/4*a - 1)
```

The first factor corresponds to the root $c_2=a/2=\sqrt 2/2$.
The second factor has three complex roots, one of them only is real:

```
sage: (C^3 + (1/2*a + 2)*C^2 + (a + 1/2)*C + 1/4*a - 1).roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=False)
[0.2450771921250444?,
 -1.476091986655796? - 0.6774060585198529?*I,
 -1.476091986655796? + 0.6774060585198529?*I]
```

And the real value above corresponds to the (numerical) one delivered by pari/gp.

Its exact expression is as follows.
Let us introduce:
$$
\begin{aligned}
S &= \frac 1{54}\Big(23 + \sqrt 2 + 3\sqrt{3(13+6\sqrt 2)}\Big)\ ,\\
T &= \frac 1{54}\Big(23 + \sqrt 2 - 3\sqrt{3(13+6\sqrt 2)}\Big)\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{Then the needed unknown root $c_1$ is:} \\
c_1 &= -\frac 16(4+\sqrt 2) + S^{1/3}+ T^{1/3}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
And the corresponding $x$-solution is obtained by taking arccos of $c_1$.

Let us check this (numerically):

```
sage: a = sqrt(2); var('C');
sage: pol = (C^3 + (1/2*a + 2)*C^2 + (a + 1/2)*C + 1/4*a - 1)
sage: S = (+3*sqrt(3)*sqrt(6*sqrt(2) + 13) + sqrt(2) + 23)/54
sage: T = (-3*sqrt(3)*sqrt(6*sqrt(2) + 13) + sqrt(2) + 23)/54
sage: c1 = -(4+sqrt(2))/6 + S^(1/3) + T^(1/3)

sage: c1.n(300)
0.245077192125044320885533690172454078574209158947516128685299866370128824596821778908696124

sage: pol.roots(ring=RealField(300), multiplicities=False)
[0.245077192125044320885533690172454078574209158947516128685299866370128824596821778908696122]

sage: x1 = acos(c1)
sage: x1.n(250)
1.3231970148034460170431250253951876668350360601328894523066983942144393866
```

This corresponds also to the numerical solution given by pari/gp when asked for...

```
? solve(x=Pi/3, Pi/2, sin(x) + sin(x)*cos(x) - (1/sqrt(2) + 1/2))
%17 = 1.3231970148034460170431250253951876668350360601328894523066983942144393866408301
```